# Safari overflow: hidden, right margin bug

Tags: html, css, safari

I use this code to create a 2 column layout:

```
<style type="text/css">
#column-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#column1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#column2 {
    background-color: lime;
    margin-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 200px;
}
</style>
<div id="column-wrap">
    <div id="column1">Column 1</div>
    <div id="column2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

It works well in all browsers except Safari (5.1.7), if I use the `overflow: hidden;` property in the second column, Safari displays a large empty margin on the right side.

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#column2`

Comment: I know it fixes the problem but i need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you want something like this, but try the below example ->

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwe3/3/)

Remove `margin-left:200px` from `#column2`

```
#column2 {
    background-color: lime;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 200px;
    }
```

Your `#column2` will automatically float left as you aren't clearing its `float` property and thus no need for the `margin-left`

Tested and working in Safari 5.1.7 (Windows).

Comment: The second column has to have full width.

Comment: @w-d, the second column width needs to fill the screen not just it's contents.

Comment: @w-d yes but the first column has to have a fixed width. I tried making the second column 100% but in Safari it stretches beyond the browser window.

Comment: @w-d yo removed `margin-left: 200px;` i needed it to add a bit of separation between the columns, but no matter i found a way around it. Thanks.

Comment: You can just add another `div` between those two divs  and set its `width` say `10px`. You're welcome. Glad it helped.